# subharmonic function extending to a larger domain

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have a $C^2$ subharmonic function $f$ defined on $\bar B_2(0)\setminus B_1(0)$, with $f|_{\partial B_2(0)}=0$, and $f(x)>0$ for $x\notin \partial B_2(0)$. Here $B_r(0)$ is a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ centered at $0$ with radius $r$. Can we find a $C^0$ subharmonic function $g$ defined on $\bar B_2(0)$ such that $g|_{\partial B_2(0)}=0$, $g(x)>0$ for $x\notin \partial B_2(0)$, and $g|_{\bar B_2(0)\setminus B_1(0)} \geq f$?

Comment: subharmonic functions are usually defined on open sets

Comment: Sorry. I mean that their restrictions on the open sets are subharmonic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, such a function would have to attain an interior maximum (due to the inequalities you are imposing), which is not possible for a subharmonic function. Google maximum principle for subharmonic functions to find out why if you don't know it already.

(which does not mean that your $f$ cannot exist, is just has to attain it's maximum on the inner boundary)